# Mongoose aggregate pipeline: sorting indexed date in MongoDB is slow

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I've been working with this error for some time on my App here and was hoping someone can lend a hand finding the error of this aggregation query.

I'm using a docker container running MongoDB shell version v4.2.8. The app uses an Express.js backend with Mongoose middleware to interface with the database.

I want to make an aggregation pipeline that first matches by an indexed field called 'platform_number'. We then sort that by the indexed field 'date' (stored as an ISODate type). The remaining pipeline does not seem to influence the performance, its just some projections and filtering.

`{$sort: {date: -1}}` bottlenecks the entire aggregate, even though there are only around 250 documents returned. I do have an unindexed key called 'cycle_number' that correlates directly with the 'date' field. Replacing `{date: -1}` with `{cycle_number: -1}` speeds up the query, but then I get an out of memory error. Sorting has a max 100MB cap on Ram and this sort fails with 250 documents.

A possible solution would be to include the additional option `{ "allowDiskUse": true }`. But before I do, I want to know why 'date' isn't sorting properly in the first place. Another option would be to index 'cycle_number' but again, why does 'date' throw up its hands?

The aggregation pipeline is provided below. It is first a match, followed by the sort and so on. I'm happy to explain what the other functions are doing, but they don't make much difference when I comment them out.

```
    let agg = [ {$match: {platform_number: platform_number}} ] // indexed number
    agg.push({$sort:  {date: -1}}) // date is indexed in decending order
    if (xaxis && yaxis) {
        agg.push(helper.drop_missing_bgc_keys([xaxis, yaxis]))
        agg.push(helper.reduce_bgc_meas([xaxis, yaxis]))
    }
    const query = Profile.aggregate(agg)

    query.exec(function (err, profiles) {
        if (err) return next(err)
        if (profiles.length === 0) { res.send('platform not found') }
        else {
            res.json(profiles)
        }
    })
```

Once again, I've been tiptoeing around this issue for some time. Solving the issue would be great, but understanding the issue better is also awesome, Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query executor is not able to use a different index for the second stage.  MongoDB indexes map the key values to the location of documents in the data files.
Once the `$match` stage has completed, the documents are in the pipeline, so no further index use is possible.

However, if you create a compound index on `{platform_number:1, date:-1}` the query planner can combine the `$match` and `$sort` stages into a single stage that will not require a blocking sort, which should greatly improve the performance of this pipeline.

Comment: That did it. [Here](https://argovis.colorado.edu/ng/profview?platform_number=2903354&topChart=doxy&bottomChart=temp&leftChart=%7B%22x1%22:%22temp%22,%22x2%22:%22pres%22%7D&middleChart=%7B%22x1%22:%22psal%22,%22x2%22:%22pres%22%7D&rightChart=%7B%22x1%22:%22psal%22,%22x2%22:%22temp%22%7D&bgcPlatform=true&selectedIndex=0) is the application in action!